# sudo: psql: command not found: can't fix it

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, psql, postgresql-9.5

When I run

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

I get the

```
sudo: psql: command not found
```

error. I can't get it to work.

```
# locate psql
/etc/alternatives/psql.1.gz
/usr/bin/psql
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/psql
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcpsqlS.so
/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/psql.1.gz
/var/lib/postgresql/.psql_history
```

and

```
# ln -s /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/psql /usr/bin/psql
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/psql': File exists
```

Didn't work. Postgresql is running and doing fine, though.

Comment: Can you share output of `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

Set up `postgres`' `PATH` variable in `.bash_profile` to contain `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

copy the psql binary from the postgreql bin folder to /usr/bin

```
 sudo cp -v /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/psql /usr/bin/
```

Comment: Manually writing files to a path that's supposed to be managed by the package manager is a bad idea.